# .htaccess: Route LAST "folder" to parameter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, accelerated-mobile-page

Due to changes while updating a site, I have to re-route the AMP-Sites. 
We use WordPress with permalinks like

```
/topicA/articleB/
/topicC/articleD/
```

To get the AMP-Result, there had to be a trailing /amp e.g.

```
/topicA/articleB/amp
/topicC/articleD/amp
```

Now, with the new AMP-Plugin it needs a trailing ?amp, like

```
/topicA/articleB?amp
/topicC/articleD?amp
```

How can I match those with .htaccess and redirect them correctly?